# Syntax error in this stored procedure, what's wrong?

Tags: stored-procedures, syntax-error

I'm trying to write a stored procedure that should insert data into a table only for records within the range of 0 and 350.

It gets two integers as a parameter

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_MesaEnRango
    (@nroMesa INT,
     @cantidadVotantes INT)
AS
BEGIN 
    IF @nroMesa IS NOT NULL OR @cantidadVotantes IS NOT NULL OR
       @cantidadVotantes < 0 OR @cantidadVotantes > 350
    BEGIN 
        DECLARE @errorMessage NVARCHAR(50);

        BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        BEGIN TRY
            INSERT INTO Mesas (nroMesa, cantidadVotantes)
            VALUES (@nroMesa, @cantidadVotantes);
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            SET @errorMessage = 'ERROR';

            IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            BEGIN 
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
            END;
        END CATCH;

        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        BEGIN 
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END;
    END;
```

I get a syntax error near to ';'

Comment: I fixed formatting.

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Side note: if this is for **SQL Server** (you didn't specify...) you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an `END` at the very end to complete the procedure body.  If you indent consistently and keep your `BEGIN`s and `END`s lined up, you'll have an easier time spotting these kinds of issues.  Here's a reformatted version of your code with the missing `END` added:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_MesaEnRango
    (@nroMesa int,
    @cantidadVotantes int)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @nroMesa IS NOT NULL OR
        @cantidadVotantes IS NOT NULL OR
        @cantidadVotantes < 0 OR
        @cantidadVotantes > 350
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @errorMessage nvarchar(50);

        BEGIN TRANSACTION;

        BEGIN TRY
            INSERT INTO Mesas (nroMesa,cantidadVotantes)
            VALUES (@nroMesa,@cantidadVotantes);
        END TRY

        BEGIN CATCH
            SET @errorMessage = 'ERROR';
            IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            BEGIN 
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
            END
        END CATCH

        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        BEGIN 
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END
    END
END
```